# Confusion matrix with a four-level class in R

Tags: r, classification, confusion-matrix

I am trying to get a confusion matrix from a multi-level factor variable (Rating)

My data looks like this:

```
> head(credit)
   Income    Rating Cards Age Education Gender Student Married Ethnicity Balance
1  14.891       bad     2  34        11   Male      No     Yes Caucasian     333
2 106.025 excellent     3  82        15 Female     Yes     Yes     Asian     903
3 104.593 excellent     4  71        11   Male      No      No     Asian     580
4 148.924 excellent     3  36        11 Female      No      No     Asian     964
5  55.882      good     2  68        16   Male      No     Yes Caucasian     331
6  80.180 excellent     4  77        10   Male      No      No Caucasian    1151
```

I built a classification tree with the rpart() function then predicted probabilities.

```
credit_model <- rpart(Rating ~ ., data=credit_train, method="class")
credit_pred <- predict(credit_model, credit_test)
```

Then I want to assess the prediction with CrossTable() from the gmodels package.

```
library(gmodels)
CrossTable(credit_test, credit_pred, prop.chisq=FALSE, prop.c=FALSE, prop.r=FALSE, dnn=c("actual Rating", "predicted Rating"))
```

But I get this error:

> Error in CrossTable(credit_test, credit_pred, prop.chisq = FALSE,
>   prop.c = FALSE,  :    x and y must have the same length

I don't know why I get this error for a 4-level class. When I have a binary class it works fine.

Comment: credit_test is a dataframe or matrix, while credit_pred is vector.

Comment: You're right, but with credit_test$Rating it doesn't work. I don't know how to fix this issue